# Overwrite an existing directory?

Tags: command-line, backup, directory, mkdir

I have a directory name `foo` located in `~/Desktop`. Suppose I want to create a directory from a terminal with same name and in the same location. When I tried `mkdir` it gave an error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/nux/Desktop/foo': File exists
```

Thats makes sense, but I want to replace `foo` if exists. I looked through [`man mkdir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mkdir.1.html) but there isn't any option that do that.

So how to overwrite `foo` directory?

Why doesn't `mkdir` have an option to do this?

Comment: Replace `foo` as in delete all contents of it? `mkdir` has a `-p` option which ignores if the directory exists.

Comment: downvoters just clarify why that , am asking about one command that delete an existing directory

Comment: @nux to me the question makes no sense ... explain why you ever want to delete and recreate a directory. We have commands for anything  you need to do to the directory. mkdir does not need a option to remove/recreate.

Comment: is it a crime here if am asking a logic question !!

Comment: Do you need to delete everything inside the directory? If not, and you just want to not have the error, mkdir -p is the option for you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If your goal is to execute a one-line command that:

- Removes and recreates the directory `~/Desktop/foo` if it already exists.
- Just creates the directory `~/Desktop/foo` if it does not already exist.

Then you can use:

```
rm -r ~/Desktop/foo; mkdir ~/Desktop/foo
```

`;` is equivalent to a newline, but it lets you execute multiple commands on a single line (i.e., as a "single command").

- If the directory you're removing may contain readonly files, you'll need the `-f` flag to remove them without prompting the user interactively. This is okay, but I do recommend being especially careful with `rm -rf ...`. See [`man rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/rm.1.html) for details.
- You need the `rm` command to *finish* before the `mkdir` command executes; this is the reason to use `;` instead of `&`. (A command preceding `&` runs asynchronously in the background.)
- You need the `mkdir` command to run when the `rm` command succeeds; this is the reason to use `;` instead of `||`.
- You need the `mkdir` command to run when the `rm` command fails (usually failure will mean the directory didn't already exist); this is the reason to use `;` instead of `&&`.
- The `rm` command might fail even when the directory already existed, in which case the `mkdir` command will fail also, but the error messages will make sense and there's probably no need to add a middle step checking for `foo`'s existence before trying to create it.

See [3.2.3 Lists of Commands](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) for more information and explanation about the `;`, `&`, `||`, and `&&` operators.

As [muru suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517329/create-and-replace-an-existing-directory#comment702271_517330) (and [Rinzwind elaborated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517329/create-and-replace-an-existing-directory#comment702283_517330)), **I do recommend you look into [`rsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/rsync.1.html)** to see if it will meet your backup needs. There are some additional useful guides on the [rsync documentation page](https://rsync.samba.org/documentation.html), as well as [this Ubuntu rsync guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync).

> why mkdir doesn't has this option ?

[`mkdir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mkdir.1.html) creates directories (the "mk" [stands for "make"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mkdir)). For it also to recursively delete directories and all the files in them would be bad, because it would violate the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) in a way that would likely lead to data loss.

[`rmdir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rmdir.1.html) doesn't even remove directories that have any (non-directory) files in them. [`rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/rm.1.html) has an `-r` option, which makes sense since `rm` is expected to remove files (that is its purpose, thus the inherent danger is intuitive and users typically know to be careful when running `rm` commands).

Comment: +1 excellent. This answer goes above and beyond in explaining the syntax, something I wish was more profound on stackexchange sites. There are a lot of golden nuggets in this answer.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no single command to do what you are asking.

Why?

> > This is the Unix philosophy: Write programs that do one thing and do it well. Write programs to work together.<sup>1</sup>

In this instance, the `mkdir` and `rm` commands do what you require, and work well together, since `rm -r` will delete the directory as well, so a subsequent `mkdir` will create the directory.

<sup>1</sup>*[The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html)*, Eric S. Raymond, itself quoting Doug McIlroy.

Comment: for now , thats a good answer , i will search for that

Answer (score 3):

The command to remove a directory is `rm`. So you need 2 commands.

```
rm -r ~/Desktop/foo/
mkdir ~/Desktop/foo/
```

As shown in comments you can chain them with  `;` (= do both even if 1st fails) or `&&` (= only mkdir when the rm does not fail).

The `-r` is for removing  dirs. The 1st command also removes ALL contents of the directory. If that is NOT your intention both rm and mkdir are not what you are looking for: permissions are `chmod` and `chown`.

> why mkdir doesn't has this option ?

Ambiguity. `mkdir` means make directory. Not remove and make directory. And since the `rm` command is for deleting stuff there is no need for `rmdir` to be able to remove a directory.

Comment: i know that , but i mean one command , you can view my edit i change it

Comment: 1st explain why you need to recreate the directory. That makes NO sense to me.

Comment: is my need make sense , i just wonder how ? it make sense for me :)

Comment: @nux no it does not. And neither does the maintainer of mkdir understand why ;) What you want is useless and has no merit.

Comment: ok if you want to know am making a script to make backup in a new directory with the same name of foo and allows replace it if exist to reduce space

Comment: foo contain backup files

Comment: @nux You should be using rsync for that. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: please understand my question , just need to know if there is a command that do that.

@muru i know about rsync

Comment: @nux backup files... you need to research "rsync" not mkdir. rsync has options for what you explained in comments.

Answer (score 3):

To do that in the cleanest way I use this:

```bash
create_clean_directory(){
    dir_name=$1
    if [ -d "$dir_name" ]; then
        echo "Removing $dir_name"
        rm -rf "$dir_name"
    elif [ -f "$dir_name" ]; then
        echo "File with this name already exists, not a directory."
        exit
    fi
    if mkdir "$dir_name"; then
        echo "Clean directory created: $dir_name"
        return 0
    else
        echo "Creating directory failed: $dir_name"
        return 1
    fi 
}
```

And to use it:

```bash
create_clean_directory <dir_name>
```

This makes sure that what you are trying to remove is a directory and not a file:

1. `-d` Check if a directory with that name already exists. if so, delete it.
2. `-f` Check that no file with this name exists. if so, print error message and exit.
3. Create the new directory and echo success, or if failed, echo failed.